# LaTeX to "freeform" converter

Tags: parsing, latex

I would like to develop a converter that will accept math written in "freeform" or something like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) would accept. For example: `2*x+(7+y)/(z^2)` will be transformed to `2\cdot x+\frac{7+y}{z^{2}}` (please ignore any syntax mistakes I might have made here) and vice versa. I was wondering if there exists a LaTeX library for C++/Java that parses and/or holds LaTeX expression in memory. If so, please share.

If not, how would you go about writing something like this? Is it okay to use normal Java/C++ code for this or should I use something like lex?

Comment: Parsing TeX is a really really complicated task. Even the power of Lex/Yacc is not enough, as the syntax may be changed on the fly. Consider `\catcode` changes, for example. The best means to parse TeX is perhaps the Knuth's original [TEX.WEB](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web). Converting the other way is considerably simpler.

Comment: @Vlad it shouldn't parse all latex syntax. Only single math expressions (not multi-line, etc.).

Comment: @Vlad I don't have a well defined list, I'm kicking this idea around for now. It should at list include `\frac{..}{..}`,`^{..}`,`_{..}`, different functions (`\sin`, `\cos`, `\max`, etc.), `\sqrt`, `\log`, `\root{..}{..}`, etc.

Comment: @Amir: Well, I would say that a lex/yacc grammar would be simpler and cleaner (especially with the latest versions supporting classes etc.), but YMMV.

Comment: What is the input and what is the output?  The question says "Latex to freeform", but your example says (user input?) freeform to Latex (inteded for compilation is a Latex document)?  How do I need a Latex parser to accept math written in freeform?

Comment: @Charles It should go both ways (resisting the urge to say "like thirteen").

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutely OK to write the parser for ‘freeform’ in Flex/Bison, in fact I’d recommend against using TeX, as that language was not written for parsing. I even remember having done exactly that (‘freeform’ to LaTeX) as an exercise with Flex and Bison and [Kimwitu++](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/sam/kimwitu++/), which allowed to perform arbitrary transformations before output. Note that you dropped the parentheses of your original formula. This might of might not be what you want in the general case.

For the other way round, the comments already mentioned that it’s nearly impossible to do in the general case. For restricted cases, Bison is good enough.